# CMake link static library error, while with NDK works fine

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, cmake

I'm trying to build my native library with CMake in latest Android Studio. I prepared gradle scripts for this, no any problems, but I found a small problem - I can not compile my library for x86 arch.

Some time before...
My library uses OpenSSL AES/DES encryption/decryption. I compiled OpenSSL 1.0.2k as is (static library), linked it to my shared library and all was fine except x86 arch - there was an error `shared library text segment is not shareable` while `dlopen` on then device. Then I recompiled OpenSSL with `-fPIC` flag, linked it again and error went away. I was building with NDK 13b.

Now...
I am trying to migrate from NDK to CMake because it is has more features for me and Android Studio can normally autocomplete and lint C/C++ code only with CMake. I wrote `CMakeList.txt` and it works, but problem with `shared library text segment is not shareable` appeared again, but on linkage step of CMake build process. Error:

```
D:/User/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin\ld: warning: shared library text segment is not shareable
  D:/User/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin\ld: error: treating warnings as errors
```

I disabled treating this warning as error and `shared library text segment is not shareable` appeared while `dlopen` on the device again.

What is the problem? Why NDK builds without any problems and CMake does not?

P.S. I tried different `CMAKE` flags (such as `CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE`) and nothing works. This problem occurrs only for `x86` arch.

CMakeLists.txt (Build failed for x86, all others - no problems):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

include_directories(include/)
find_library(log-lib log)
add_library(libcrypto STATIC IMPORTED)
add_library(libssl STATIC IMPORTED)
add_library(testlib SHARED test.c)

set_target_properties(libcrypto
                      PROPERTIES
                      IMPORTED_LOCATION
                      ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/static/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcrypto.a)
set_target_properties(libssl
                      PROPERTIES
                      IMPORTED_LOCATION
                      ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/static/${ANDROID_ABI}/libssl.a)

target_link_libraries(testlib libcrypto libssl ${log-lib})

set (CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE TRUE)
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -fPIC")
set(CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS} -fPIC")
```

Android.mk (NDK14b, All archs - no problems):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/static/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libcrypto.a
LOCAL_MODULE := crypto
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/static/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libssl.a
LOCAL_MODULE := ssl
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LCOAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.c
LOCAL_MODULE := testlib
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := crypto ssl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was that I need to compile OpenSSL with `no-asm` flag. After that OpenSSL linked and worked normally on x86 arch.

Answer (score 0):

```
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wall -v -Wl, --no-warn-shared-textrel")
```

this exact toolcain is `treating warnings as errors`, so just add this to suppress the warning. **--no-warn-shared-textrel** is the key

Comment: 1. `--no-warn-shared-textrel` is an unknown option for CMake
2. If I remove treating warnings as errors from linker flags, I get `library has text rellocations` on the x86 device while `System.loadLibrary` call.
That's why is not a solution for me.

Comment: add `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")` before linker flags

Comment: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")` does not help

Comment: This will generate binaries that will not load if you're targeting newer versions of Android: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md#Text-Relocations-Enforced-for-API-level-23.

Answer (score 0):

just in x86, add --no-warn-shared-textrel, you should add this to CMakeList.txt:

if (${ANDROID_ABI} STREQUAL "x86")
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--no-warn-shared-textrel")
endif ()

good luck.

Comment: after this library compiled, but there is a crash while runtime on x86 device: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: has text relocations`